# Git merge on remote or local

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a github repository with master branch. From master I create a local **feature_A** branch and push it to the origin. Then I create a local **feature_A_details** branch, which just alters a few details.

My question is:

If I want to merge **feature_A_details** into **feature_A** should I do it via pull request on github or should I merge it locally and then commit and push into feature_A on origin?

What is the best practise for this scenario? Merge locally and commit/push or push both and then merge on origin via pull request (merge request, etc...)

Comment: Can you give us details about how you created `feature_A_details`?  From which branch did you create this branch?

Comment: I created feature_A_details from feature_A

Comment: Have you already pushed the `feature_A` branch to GitHub?  If you haven't yet done this, then I don't see any reason to not merge `feature_A_details` locally.

Comment: yes I have. To clarify my question: Should I also push feature_A_details and merge on origin or merge locally and then push feature_A.
The output should be the same as I believe

Comment: Well, that honestly depends on whether you want the details branch to become subject to the public GitHub pull request reviewal process.  If you view the details branch as just a bunch of commits which you want to add to `feature_A` locally, then do the merge locally.  Otherwise, maybe create a pull request and let others review the work in details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer gentleman

Comment: where? and how?

Comment: Pick your favorite `:-)`